# segmentation fault while reading from a file

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a problem with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ISBNPrefix.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    FILE* file = NULL;
    int area = 0, i = 0;
    long s;

    file = open("swagger.txt");
    fscanf(file, "%ld", &s);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

and here's ISBNPrefix.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ISBNPrefix.h"
using namespace std;

FILE* open(const char filename[]) {

    FILE* file = NULL;
    file = fopen("filename", "r");

    if (file != NULL)
        return file;
    else return NULL;
}
```

my ISBNPrefix.h

```
FILE* open (const char filename[]);
```

And the content of swagger.txt is: `123456789`

When I try to run it to test if it copies the 123456789 into my variable i get a segmentation fault!

Comment: Also, `open` takes at least 2 args and returns `int`, not `FILE *`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr i've tried multiple data types, long, double, int etc.. all get segmentation fault i don't think it's the data type thats the problem

Comment: @H2CO3 I posted my ISBNPrefix.h file and the return type is of FILE not int and it takes 1 argument.

Comment: Change the name of `open` to something that doesn't conflict with a library function. Also, you need to check if `file` is `NULL` before you pass it to `fscanf`. Also, that whole `if`/`else` in the end of your `open` function is equivalent to `return file;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problem in your function for opening a file:

```
FILE* open(const char filename[]) {
    FILE* file = NULL;
    file = fopen("filename", "r"); <-- here
```

it should be `file = fopen(filename, "r");`

Also you designed `open` function to return `NULL` if there is no file, but then you don't check its return value once you call it:

```
file = open("swagger.txt");
if (file == NULL) ...        <-- you should check the return value
fscanf(file, "%ld", &s);
```

Also note that `fopen` and `fscanf` are C-style functions. Since you are using C++, there are other more convenient means how to read data from a file. Have a look at [`std::ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/). Also when you work with C headers in C++, you should include their C++ wrappers: `cstdio`, `cstdlib`, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "i don't use it that way" when I return NULL? Doesn't it do nothing if it returns NULL.

Comment: @user1895783: If your function returns `NULL` in case there is some problem, then caller of this function should check the return value whether some problem has occurred.

Comment: wouldn't the return value be NULL meaning that a problem has occured?

Comment: @user1895783: Right, so you need to check for that when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You need [fopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) for a start. Where does `ISBNPrefix.cpp` come into the picture?

Comment: My fopen is in my ISBNPrefix.cpp. My main function calls the "FILE* open" function and is supposed to return the file pointer that it opened.